# Last thread is not executing

Tags: java, multithreading

I am very new to multithreading, was trying a scenario in which a home has a mother(as producer),son,daughter and husband[As consumer] thread.I am trying to understand how wait and notify method can help here.

My classes are as below.

### MotherAsProducer

```
package com.test.All.Threads;

public enum MotherAsProducer {

INSTANCE;

    /*
     * 
     * 
     * son Give request to prepare chapati to mother
     * mother accepts it and start preparing , son/husband/daughter should wait by that time.
     * mother notifies son/daughtor/husband that chapati is ready start consuming
     * */


    public synchronized void  takeOrderAndMakeChapati(){

        try {
            System.out.println("Request got from "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            getStatusOfChapati();
            wait();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ate chapati");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //lock re-entrance
    public  synchronized void getStatusOfChapati(){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1200);
            System.out.println("Chapati is prepared for "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            notifyAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static MotherAsProducer getMotherInstance(){

        return MotherAsProducer.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

### SonAsConsumer class

```
package com.test.All.Threads;

public class SonAsConsumer implements Runnable{

    public void run(){

            MotherAsProducer.getMotherInstance().takeOrderAndMakeChapati();

    }

}
```

### DaughterAsConsumer class

```
package com.test.All.Threads;

public class DaughterAsConsumer implements Runnable {

    public void run(){

        MotherAsProducer.getMotherInstance().takeOrderAndMakeChapati();

    }

}
```

### HusbandAsConsumer class

```
package com.test.All.Threads;

public class HusbandAsConsumer implements Runnable {

    public void run(){

        MotherAsProducer.getMotherInstance().takeOrderAndMakeChapati();
    }

}
```

### Home class

```
package com.test.All.Threads;

public class Home {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SonAsConsumer sac = new SonAsConsumer();
        DaughterAsConsumer dac = new DaughterAsConsumer();
        HusbandAsConsumer hac = new HusbandAsConsumer();

        Thread tsac = new Thread(sac);
        tsac.setName("Son");
        Thread tdac = new Thread(dac);
        tdac.setName("Daughter");
        Thread thac = new Thread(hac);
        thac.setName("Husband");


        tsac.start();
        tdac.start();
        thac.start();
    }
}
```

My output is different, every time as expected by nature of thread but one of the individual either husband, daughtor or son is not getting complete.
one instance of my output is as below.

```
Order she got from Daughter
Chapati is prepared for Daughter
Order she got from Son
Chapati is prepared for Son
Order she got from Husband
Chapati is prepared for Husband
Son ate chapati
Daughter ate chapati
```

My understanding here is when son,daughter and husband will start executing one of them will hit the synchronized method and execute wait() and will hold the lock , from that synchronized method again another synchronized method is called which will contain notify and the lock will be released and another thread will try to get the lock from the blocked pool and will execute in the same manner . here two threads are behaving as expected but the last one is not. 
Kindly help here.

Comment: Now I know what a chapati is ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly looking, it looks like the last thread to get to the wait will never get notified.  Sequencing your calls you have each thread getting a lock, notifying all waiting threads, and then waiting.  So, the last thread that hits the wait will never have anyone to notify them that they need to exit.

That is, if Thread A gets the lock initially, then it will do a println and a sleep then a println, then notify all waiting threads (there are none), and then become a waiting thread.

Then, lets say Thread B gets the lock.  It will do a println and a sleep, then it will notify all (which will "notify" Thread A), then it will wait.

Now, either Thread C or Thread A will get the lock.  If Thread A gets it, it will simply fall through and complete with the "ate" message.  Then, Thread C can get the lock and it will eventually notify, waking B which can eat once C "waits".  Now, there is no thread left to notify so that C will complete.

This make sense?  Did I misread anything?

To verify what I'm suggesting is wrong, simply add in more threads.  You should always have the last one that prints "Chapati is prepared for ..." will never eat it.

Fundamentally, I think the confusion is that "Mother" is not actually doing any work.  What you probably wanted is to have "Mother" be a thread that has its own work log.  So, when one of the other threads gives her work, you set a variable then notify mother and wait as the sibling.  The mother will then wake up and do the work and notify the current thread waiting.

See what I mean?  Metaphorically, you have 4 people in this program.  But, you only have 3 threads.

Comment: Couple of questions can not be a answer! Comment in question and get clarification before answer.

Comment: My answer is simply that it is acting as expected.  The last thread to wait will never have a thread notify it.  I'll reword to make that clearer.

Comment: Just updated again with what I think the ultimate confusion on this is.  Looks like is wanted is for "Mother" to be a thread that is waiting on orders for chapati.  Is that right?  (I can briefly sketch that out, if it will help understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the method in the enum class MotherAsProducer as follows: The unnecessary wait() method caused the issue. Since the method is synchronized, all other threads will be blocked before entering into the method until getting a notification from lock holding thread.

public synchronized void takeOrderAndMakeChapati() {

```
    System.out.println("Request got from "  + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    getStatusOfChapati();
   // wait(); - THIS WAIT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " ate chapati");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `wait` and `notifyAll` calls from both `takeOrderAndMakeChapati` and `getStatusOfChapati`. You will get the expected result.

As precisely mentioned by Josh, one of the threads (last one) is still `wait`ing for some external notification, and there is nobody to notify. You code is still running in the background. Just call `wait(5000)` and you can see it happening.

Both methods `takeOrderAndMakeChapati` and `getStatusOfChapati` are synchronized, therefore synchronization is not the issue.

*Generally* threads `wait` for some external dependency or condition, where some other thread(s) notifies the waiting one, when that condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to understand `wait` and `notify` when I started with multithreading. But as soon as I learned to use a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), I never looked back. Hopefully, the example below will give you some insight into the benefits of using a Semaphore. There is also a lot more useful stuff in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package that can be of great help.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class EatChapati {

static int CHAPATI_PREPARE_TIME_MS = 100;
static long RUN_TIME_MS = 2000;
static long SHUTDOWN_TIME_MS = 500;
static int CHAPATI_CONSUMERS = 5;
static volatile boolean stop;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < CHAPATI_CONSUMERS; i++) {
        executor.execute(new ChapatiConsumer(i + 1));
    }
    try { Thread.sleep(RUN_TIME_MS); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    stop = true;
    executor.shutdownNow();
    try { executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}

// 1 producer making chapati's
// 'true' for a fair semaphore: longest waiting consumer gets served 
static Semaphore chapatiTurn = new Semaphore(1, true);
static AtomicInteger chapatiCount = new AtomicInteger();

static int getChapati(int consumerNumber) {

    int chapatiNumber = 0;
    boolean haveTurn = false;
    try {
        chapatiTurn.acquire();
        // start of 'synchronized' block
        haveTurn = true;
        Thread.sleep(CHAPATI_PREPARE_TIME_MS);
        chapatiNumber = chapatiCount.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("Chapati " + chapatiNumber + " prepared for consumer " + consumerNumber);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Triggered by executor.shutdownNow
        stop = true;
    } finally {
        if (haveTurn) {
            chapatiTurn.release();
            // end of 'synchronized' block
        }
    }
    return chapatiNumber;
}

static class ChapatiConsumer implements Runnable {

    int number;

    ChapatiConsumer(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {

        int chapatisConsumed = 0;
        while (!stop) {
            if (getChapati(number) > 0) {
                chapatisConsumed++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer " + number + " stopped after consuming " + chapatisConsumed + " chapatis.");
    }
}
}
```